# Android Espresso tests never finish

Tags: android, android-espresso

I've been struggling with getting instrumented unit tests properly working for my android project, as when I make a test class and use ActivityTestRule to run my activity, each individual test runs - but despite returning either as a success or failure, the test just never ends.
Everything works as intended, but the tests don't end, and so each test has to be ran on its own, then manually ended.
Does anyone have any idea why this might be the case?

Comment: I had a similar situation where the test never seemed to end, and it turned out that I had a view that was constantly refreshing that was causing the test to never end.  I know this is pretty generic, but maybe an idea of something to look into

Comment: That is actually what happens in the activity I want to run, there's a view that gets updated over and over - but the activity is supposed to end with every test case, and it does, so why doesn't the test end? Is there any way to end a test case manually?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found out the problem, scottymack pointed me in the right direction - I had a thread that constantly updated a View, and for some reason, ActivityTestRule didn't call onPause and onDestroy methods that would normally be called on shutdown. All it took was putting those in an @After method.